# search in string from an array of keys. PHP

Tags: php

I have a sentence like this, and array of some keys.

```
$string = "I have a sentence like this, and array of some keys"
$keys = ['have', 'like', 'some']
```

I need a resultant array which would check for the word in the string and collect the string which is followed by the particular key such as in the above sentence

```
have => a sentence
like => this, and array of
some => keys
```

i.e.

```
$result = ['have'=> 'a sentence', 'like' => 'this, and array of', 'some' => 'keys'];
```

The only hint I can provide is that I have been trying it with recursion and has been successful upto 80%, rest is quite buggy;

I am trying with this is code
where `$preps` is key and `$query` is stirng value

```
public function sep($preps, $query) {
    foreach ($preps as $prep) {
        @list($rval, $lval) = explode(" $prep ", $query);
        if($lval) {
            $this->sep[$prep] = $lval;
            $this->sep($preps, $lval);
            $this->sep($preps, $rval);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Then go for it. (Did you had a question ?)

Comment: you have to specify what should happen, if the a key word is more than one time in the string?! or doesn't exist?! what is the logic behind this generator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please take the UPDATE 2 solution, not first and second result**

following code only works if all the key words are exist inside the string. if not. errors will occur.

```
$str = "I have a sentence like this, and array of some keys.";
$keys = ['have', 'like', 'some'];
$parts = preg_split('/('.implode('|', $keys).')/i', $str);
$parts = array_slice($parts,1);
$result = array_combine($keys, $parts);
print_r($result);
```

---

**UPDATE** not a good solution, but it works:

```
$str = $modStr = "I have a sentence like this, and array of some keys.";
$keys = ['have', 'like', 'some'];
foreach($keys as $key)
    $modStr = str_replace($key, '[['.$key.']]', $modStr);
echo $modStr."<br>";
preg_match_all('/\[\[([^\]]*)\]\]([^\[]*)/i', $modStr, $parts);
print_r($parts);
```

---

**UPDATE 2** better solution:

I think this is a better solution. It is a mix of regular expression mixture and string methods:

```
$str = $modStr = "I have a sentence like this, and array of some keys.";
$keys = ['like', 'have', 'some'];
$positions = [];
// look for each key and be sure it is the whole word (finds only some, not somehow) and save the position in an array.
foreach($keys as $key)
    if(preg_match('/\b'.$key.'\b/i', $str, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))
        $positions[] = [$key, $m[0][1]];
// sort this position array:
usort($positions, function($a, $b) { return $a[1]-$b[1]; });
// now it's easy to split the string, because we have all positions.
$result = [];
for($i=0,$n=count($positions);$i<$n;$i++) {
    $kvPair = $positions[$i];
    $pos = $kvPair[1]+strlen($kvPair[0]);
    $result[$kvPair[0]] = substr($str, $pos,($i+1<$n?$positions[$i+1][1]:strlen($str))-$pos);
}
print_r($result);
```

this code works also if keys missing in the string and if a key word is followed by special characters.

Comment: Thanks buddy, It is almost working, but what if I make the $key array as ['like', 'have', 'some']. It is providing wrong output. Can u give me a solution for this. Thanks again in advance :)

Comment: @MdAdil added another solution. but I'm not happy with it

Comment: @MdAdil ah. gimme a minute. I have an idea.

Comment: thanks, It working for now, let's hope that it doesn't break in future. I wish I could give you million points for that :).

Comment: you're welcome. but I added a better solution. pls take a look at it. it should work much better.